# iOS 7 change UITableViewCell font color to blue like in Settings app

Tags: ios, uitableview, fonts, ios7

I have a `UITableview` in grouped style and there is one cell that I want to use like a button. My problem is, the font color of this cell is by default black. I want to have the same blue as font color as the cells used as buttons in the settings app (e.g. in settings/safari the delete history cell is used as a button and has this light iOS 7 styled blue as font color). I would love it if anybody could help me.
Much love, Timm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard or xib and you have a prototype cell, go in to it and select the label. Then you can set the color of the text.

If you want to do it programmatically, add the following to your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

`blueColor` isn't exactly the same as the blue used by buttons in iOS 7, but you could manually pick a color that closely approximates it if you wanted instead.

EDIT:

This will give you the exact color you want:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [button titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It's getting the color from a UIButton.

Comment: Yeah, i know, thanks. I just hope that anyone here knows the exact color Apple uses.

Comment: I just edited the answer to show how to get the exact color you want. So try this. I already tested it and it works. Please accept my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this line of code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to set up `UITableViewCell`'s font color:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    // (cell creation)...
    
    // set to the color that Apple uses
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.204 green:0.459 blue:1.000 alpha:1.0];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not what i searched for. I know how to set up the font color and stuff, i just don't know what color Apple used for their cell in Settings.app. Look at Settings.app under Safari, the font color of the "Delete history" cell ist just a light blue. I already tried [UIColor blueColor] before, it's a too dark blue.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear after reading your question description. So one approach is to just take a screenshot of this screen, launch default color picker and grab that color. Here it is — `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.204 green:0.459 blue:1.000 alpha:1.0]`

Comment: Sorry, my english isn't the best. Thank you mate, that color is good enough for me. :P

Comment: No problem, always glad to help. Feel free to mark this answer as a correct, if you think so.

Comment: That color is just an approximation, it's not exactly the same color. My answer gives you exactly the color you want.

Comment: @Gavin Sometimes it's a better idea to use an approximation than write ugly code. I think it's possible to retrieve `RGB`-colors from that `UIColor` object you get from `UIButton` and just shorten it to one line of code.

Comment: @RinatKhanov, it's very clean looking code that will also adapt to changes that Apple makes to the color, in case they tweak it a little at some point in the future. So it allows the app to maintain a consistent appearance with the rest of the OS.